# Python implementation of avro slow?

Tags: python, avro

I'm reading some data from avro file using the avro library. It takes about a minute to load 33K objects from the file. This seem very slow to me, specially with the Java version reading the same file in about 1sec.

Here is the code, am I doing something wrong?

```
import avro.datafile
import avro.io
from time import time

def load(filename):
    fo = open(filename, "rb")
    reader = avro.datafile.DataFileReader(fo, avro.io.DatumReader())
    for i, record in enumerate(reader):
        pass

    return i + 1

def main(argv=None):
    import sys
    from argparse import ArgumentParser

    argv = argv or sys.argv

    parser = ArgumentParser(description="Read avro file")


    start = time()
    num_records = load("events.avro")
    end = time()

    print("{0} records in {1} seconds".format(num_records, end - start))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything. If there is a speed problem its with avro.

Comment: `load()` should call `fo.close()` before it returns, rather than leaving the file open. It's probably not reason for the slow-down, though.

Comment: if you want to know why its slow, learn how to use a profiler.

Comment: I know how to use a profiler (or two). I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong or not.

Answer (score 4):

It appears there is a python package called `fastavro` that is a fast Cython implementation, but is less feature-complete.

https://bitbucket.org/tebeka/fastavro

Comment: Wow!! This answer needs more love. After profiling my script for a few minutes, then noticing Avro reading took up 80+% of time (there is a lot of math which should be culprit), I started the job and googled this. I was able to install, change code, benchmark (dropped to under 17% time, promoting my shitty code from 7% of time up to 70% where it should be :-) and then kicked off the same job... in a sequence of files that is alphabetical the fastavro version "caught up" before the original was halfway through the letter A. Results are byte-for-byte the same. Perfection!

Comment: For _almost_ the same amount of work (tried to quit my profile at the same point in terms of work done (as opposed to time), and the original spend 18s reading in Avro, and fastavro was less than 1 second. Dropped total script time (just for the profiling/experiment) from 21 to 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

The [avro Python package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/avro) available on PyPI is pure Python, so I'm not surprised if it is slower than Java by an order of magniture or more.

There is an Avro C implementation, but to my knowledge nobody has yet created a Python extension based on it.

Comment: Sadly, the avro c implementation segfaults on my file.

Comment: @lazy1 bummer. Are you forced to use the Avro format, and have you considered alternatives?

Comment: The alternative is CSV, which in Python is very fast (0.2 for 33K lines). However the CSV does not carry the schema like avro does. I *might* be able to use CSV headers, but since someone else is producing them (via Pig), I'm not 100% sure it's possible.

Comment: Hmm yeah, given the time discrepancy it's worth looking to faster alternatives.